# Mysql Command over SSH

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to execute a mysql query over ssh 
it works fine unless i put a where=xxx clause
can anyone guide me?
here is an example of a working one

```
ssh mysql1.server.xxx "sudo mysql -u root --execute 'SELECT * from mysql.user;'"
```

here is an example of the non working one

```
ssh mysql1.server.xxx "sudo mysql -u root --execute 'SELECT * from mysql.user where User='username';'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have nested single quotes:

```
'SELECT ... User='username';'
^                ^        ^ ^ <-- here
```

You need to escape one set of quotes. Example:

```
ssh mysql1.example.com "mysql --execute \"SELECT * from mysql.user where User='username';\""
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but if i need it in an if statement, example
run the query and if it returns a result then echo something
it seem to go straight to the then clause even if returns no result

Comment: That would be a new question. And to be honest, [so] seems more appropriate for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever you're executing commands remotely with ssh, watch out for quotation marks, as you might need to escape them, etc., or you might be accidentally nesting them.

In particular, in this case you are nesting your quotes. See your `select` statement:

> 'SELECT * from mysql.user where User='username';'

Without the `where` clause, it wasn't nested, works fine. But with the `where` clause, the problem came with the additional single quotes around `username`.